# How to create a smoke sprite for a 2d car racing game?

Tags: java, android, sprite

I am creating a educational 2d racing game in android. Now what I am stuck in is that when the car starts and start running I want to show the smoke just behind it imitating the tyre and the silencer smoke. Can any one please help me how can I achieve that.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

One simple but effective effect that I've seen is to draw transparent grey circles and animate the opacity to be more transparent over time until the circles disappear. Growing the circle over time also helps create the illusion of smoke.

Comment: Can you please provide me some code how will I do that in JAva?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java. However I have successfully used the above idea in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use particle effect from eg. http://www.rigzsoft.co.uk/ and render png frames. Than show on your game loop in specific fps.